# visual studio 2010 connectivity to db2 on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, db2-connect

I have installed the db2 drivers from the ibm enterprise connect package. I am able to connect to the db2 datasource (system dsn) when I open visual studio in an admin mode and open the integration package. But I get an sqlstate 58031 when I open visual studio in a non admin mode. What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: You "run as administrator". You select visual studio, right click and "run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working now. Needed to add the user to the db2users group and also gave the user full access over the db2 directory under programData. (At least that is what I think fixed it)